# htc explorer not loaded after factory reset

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, boot-loop

I have rooted my HTC Explorer and it worked well. Due to some memory problems, it became slow. So I did a factory reset, after that my HTC Explorer is not loading, it shows only logo screen.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Switch off your phone.Charge it to full.Then remove your battery and leave it untouched for about 2 - 3 hours.Then put the battery and try switching on.If this does not work try flashing stock firmware.